# Abelian subgroup of prime power index

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, simple-groups

I am having difficulty with the following problem.

Show that, a finite non-abelian simple group cannot have an abelian subgroup of prime power index.

What I was thinking is that I can somehow use a result by Burnside  which says that "For a finite group G having a conjugacy class of order prime power then G cannot be simple"

Kindly suggest how to proceed further.

Comment: Well, any element of such a subgroup will give you such a conjugacy class.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Are you taking the action of G on such a subgroup?

Comment: Given the context of using said result of Burnside I think my hint stands on its own. Computing the order of the conjugacy class of an element in such a subgroup should be a wellknown exercise.

Comment: Not really. Given the context, there should be no issue using standard result to find the size of the conjugacy class of an element in the abelian subgroup.

Comment: That's fine, I suppose to proceed I can take the action of G on itself by conjugation, then use the ordbit stabilizer theorem to conclude, Is it? @TobiasKildetoft

Comment: yeah, I got the solution ( by myself), thanks @TobiasKildetoft :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a non-identity element $a$ in $H$, then the centralizer of $a$ contains $H$ since $H$ is abelian.
Then the index of the centralizer of $a$ in $G$ is of prime power,
So by Burnside theorem (you stated), centralizer of $a$ is the whole group, which shows that the centre of $G$ is nontrivial. Simplicity implies $G$ has to be abelian, which is contraction to the given hypothesis.
Hence a non-abelian simple group cannot have an abelian subgroup of prime power index.

Comment: But how can centralizer containing H implies the quotient is prime power it can only say it's less then equal to, right?

Comment: H is of prime power index. So any subgroup containing H will also have prime power index

Comment: Let K be any subgroup containing H. Now order(G/K) =(|G|/|H|) (|H|/|K|).